# Resize my tensor to the size of another tensor at the graph execution time in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to resize one tensor to the size of another tensor (W, H, _) at the time when my graph executes. I only want to make the width and height same, not the channels. Channels are irrelevant.
Only channels are known at the graph generation time, so I am unable to know the W, H of the image tensor until execution. So at the time of graph execution, I'll need to find the shape and then apply resizing.

I tried to look for the code but there is no reference available. Can anyone help?

**My pipeline:**

Input Tensor 1: 200, 500, 60

Input Tensor 2: 400, 900, 90

Resize Tensor 2: 200, 500, 90 (width and Height)

Concat 1 & 2: 200, 500, 150

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected output and what you have tried so far and any errors you have got

Comment: The problem is not data dependent: I'll explain why:

Any standard data for object detection can be used. It can be in coco format or Pascal VOC. 

I have tried the following:

Get graph summary, but it gives none for the width and height because the tensor shape can change based on the dimension of the input
I have tried getting shape of the tensor at graph generation time but that's logically incorrect. I found out when I read the literature
Then there was a clue about getting width and height at graph execution time. I am now pursuing that avenue.

Comment: Can you check this operation tf.compat.v1.image.resize? Takes [height, width, channels] as input and gives [new_height, new_width, channels] as output.